# Angular 16: failed to load component through lazy loading process

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm trying to lazy load a component (`HomeComponent`) in my project. I have tried to load it by using a button (upon clicking the button the URL will be changed) and manually changing the URL. But the output seems stuck in the `app.component.html` and does not load the target component.

Here is the code from the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./main/home/home.module').then(m => m.HomeModule)
      }
    ]
    
  }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Now, here is the **home.module.ts** file. It is the component which I am trying to access.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule( {
    declarations: [ HomeComponent ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ], 
    exports: [
      RouterModule
    ]
} )
export class HomeModule {}
```

What seems to be there problem here? The console does not show any error like it cannot find the module or something. What can I do now from here?

Comment: You have configured all the paths after /home to go to HomeComponent see ** in home.module

Comment: @Navitas28 can you elaborate, please? Cannot understand your comment.

Comment: The code seems to be correct, just make sure your imports are correct './main/home/home.module', './home.component' and then make sure HomeComponent has some HTML in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the same code in my IDE, its working. I think you might have forgotten to add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the app.component.html file.

Its a placeholder to load the components dynamically.